# Laraadmin and sqlite "SHOW": syntax error (SQL: SHOW TABLES)

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laraadmin

I have installed laraadmin as for quick admin with using sqlite.
But problem is when i am going to create something getting SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "SHOW": syntax error (SQL: SHOW TABLES)
Thanks

Comment: Sqlite doesn't have a `SHOW` statement. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html for what it understands.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQLite doesn't know `SHOW TABLES`, but instead it has:

[special command line commands](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#special_commands_to_sqlite3_dot_commands_), like `.schema` or `.tables` (with optional `LIKE` patterns)

[a master metadata table](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7), called `sqlite_master`

So let's say you have the following tables:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE A(a INT, b, INT, c TEXT);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE B(a INT);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE AB(a TEXT, b TEXT);
```

You can query the schema:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE A(a INT, b, INT, c TEXT);
CREATE TABLE B(a INT);
CREATE TABLE AB(a TEXT, b TEXT);
```

Query the table names:

```
sqlite> .tables
A   AB  B
```

Query all the metadata:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';
table|A|A|2|CREATE TABLE A(a INT, b, INT, c TEXT)
table|B|B|3|CREATE TABLE B(a INT)
table|AB|AB|4|CREATE TABLE AB(a TEXT, b TEXT)
```

Query the schema of table names matching a specific `LIKE` pattern:

```
sqlite> .schema A%
CREATE TABLE A(a INT, b, INT, c TEXT);
CREATE TABLE AB(a TEXT, b TEXT);
```

Query the table names matching a specific `LIKE` pattern:

```
sqlite> .tables A%
A   AB
```